# Javac does not recognize the given classpath

Tags: servlets, classpath, javac

I badly need an advise where I am going wrong here

I have servlet-api.jar @ E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\lib

E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\lib\servlet-api.jar

I am trying to run a Servlet class "TouchServlet.java" which is at

E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\TouchServlet\src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java

So from the command prompt,

E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\TouchServlet>javac -classpath E:\j2ee\apach
e-tomcat-6.0.18\lib\servlet-api.jar src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet
.java

Note: I am executing from E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\TouchServlet

The below is the directory structures

E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\TouchServlet> **I am here**

E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\TouchServlet\src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java

E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\lib\servlet-api.jar

If I compile, I am getting the below errors

```
E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\TouchServlet>javac -classpath E:\j2ee\apach
e-tomcat-6.0.18\lib\servlet-api.jar src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet
.java

src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java:4: package java.servlet does n
ot exist
import java.servlet.*;
^
src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java:5: package java.servlet.http d
oes not exist
import java.servlet.http.*;
^
src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol: class HttpServlet
class TouchServlet extends HttpServlet
                           ^
src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class com.saravanansivaji.servlet.TouchServlet
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respon
se)
                          ^
src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class com.saravanansivaji.servlet.TouchServlet
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respon
se)
                                                      ^
src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class com.saravanansivaji.servlet.TouchServlet
                throws ServletException, IOException {
                       ^
6 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\TouchServlet> javac -classpath "E:\j2ee\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\lib\servlet-api.jar" TouchServlet.java

Comment: E:\J2EE\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\webapps\TouchServlet>javac -classpath "E:\j2ee\apac
he-tomcat-6.0.18\lib\servlet-api.jar" src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServl
et.java

Comment: Still I am facing the same issue

Comment: src\com\saravanansivaji\servlet\TouchServlet.java:4: package java.servlet does not exist
import java.servlet.*;